# What are the consequences of extending sessions max timeout in the apache php.ini file?

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies

I'm setting up a website, and I'd rather not put cookies on people's computers.  Is it bad practice - or worse- insanely insecure to extend the sessions max timeout to a day or two days?

```
    session_regenerate_id();
    $profileid = $userdata['userid'];
    $profile = $userdata['username'];
    //Set session
    $_SESSION['profileid'] = $profileid;
    //Put name in session
    $_SESSION['profile'] = $profile;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

Edit:  Added code.
Edit:  the php.ini line that I would modify is:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Comment: how are the session id's parsed?

Comment: you mean `session.gc_maxlifetime`?

Comment: It's no more insecure than any other use of session data. The only consequence is additional data storage on your server for the duration of the session length.

Comment: to be honest, i am not sure.  i will update the post with how i generate the session...

Comment: @lawrence  Yes, exactly.

Comment: when you don't know what your doing, sticking to 'standard practice' is usually a good idea.

Comment: @tjones Even when using sessions you will still be putting cookies on the user's computer (albeit just containing the PHPSESSID). Just thought it might be worth pointing out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which
>   data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage
>   collection may occur during session start (depending on
>   session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

This value (default 1440 seconds or [24 Minutes]) defines how long an unused PHP session will be kept alive.

**For example:** A user logs in, browses through your application or web site, for hours, for days. No problem. As long as the time between his clicks never exceed 1440 seconds. It's a timeout value,

PHP's session garbage collector runs with a probability defined by [session.gc_probability](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) divided by [session.gc_divisor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor). By default this is 1/100, which means that above timeout value is checked with a probability of 1 in 100.

So increasing this value will most likely not have much effect on your script unless you expect your users not to click around your site. Like in the case of a logged in user watching a long video and then after watching find themselves logged out afterwards. If this is the case perhaps you should use a some javascript to poll the server every 20mins to keep the session open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything particularly insecure about it, as long as your code in general is secure.

However

a) The user will lose their data if they close the browser - which they might do for any reason. If you need to ensure that data is kept around for a longer period, between sessions, unless the user specifically opts out, use cookies. Otherwise, it seems kind of counter-productive to insist on no-cookies. To clarify, I think what I mean is, if the standard session lifetime isn't long enough, then you probably shouldn't be using $_SESSION to store the data. By it's nature, $_SESSION is ephemeral and can only be used for fairly ephemeral things.

b) Unless you're really going an extra mile to prevent all cookies, the PHP Session id will be set using a cookie anyway, so are you really doing your users any favours?